# Setting Corner Radius on ImageView is imperfect in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I am using `imageView`s in my app to which I set `cornerRadius` to make them circular. All that works fine, but when I verify it in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, some parts at the edge seem cut off, for eg. the top part in the image below:

[image]

Note that I haven't added 3x launch image, so the app is actually displayed as a scaled version of the original.
I am assuming this issue happens because of the scaling factor. i.e. the width I specify in code is not what I actually see in the device. Also, I assume this will be fixed if I use autoLayout.

Are my assumptions correct? If not, please provide an explanation and a solution for the same. Thanks :) !

**EDIT1:**

My imageView is of `35 x 35` size.
I set the corner radius as follows:

```
[commentCell.profileImageView.layer setCornerRadius:17.5];
[commentCell.profileImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

**EDIT2:**

Floating points doesn't seem to be it, because I tried the same with frame size `36 x 36` and corner radius `18`.

Comment: Add some code here. so, anyone can judge.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are correct, however there is another solution too :

```
[commentCell.profileImageView.layer setCornerRadius:profileImageView.frame.size.width/2];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, you can try the one mentioned in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too, probably is due to float rounding.
You can try 2 things:

- mask the image view layer with a CAShapeLayer
- redraw the image in a circle

L

```
CAShapeLayer *circleClipLayer=[CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath * circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[circlePath addArcWithCenter:yourcenter radius:yourradius startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
circleClipLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;
yourimageview.layer.mask=circleClipLayer;
```

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work. Also, it must be `circlePath` instead of `bezierPath` in line 3 right?

Comment: I've tried right know on a code of mine and it's working, pay attention to calculate exact center CAShapeLayer *circleClipLayer=[CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath * circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(imageview.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(imageview.bounds)) radius:imageview.bounds.size.width/2 startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
    circleClipLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;
    imageview.layer.mask=circleClipLayer;

Comment: Yep. I did the exact same way. are you sure you tried that in iPhone 6 or 6 Plus? You haven't used autolayout? and you haven't added a 3x launch image?

Comment: I'm using autolayout I've tried on both simulators and I have a 3x image, I suggest you to check views frame before adding the mask

Comment: I did check frames before applying mask. I did check frame of the window and the UIScreen too. But it all shows the same width of the scaled version. Using autoLayout fixes the issue. I have mentioned this in my question. Please check the question again.